# testing statistical significance from joint independent non-identical experiments

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a simple question in statistical hypothesis testing, and I should clarify that I know very little about statistics. Consider a collection of $N$ experiments. For each experiment I can construct a discrete distribution of outcomes $p^{(r)}_x$, where $r$ is a label for the experiment (so $r=1,\dots, N$), and $x$ is an outcome in the experiment. Each $p^{(r)}_x$ is unimodal in the sense of having a unique maximum, i.e. the only local maximum is also the global maximum. The distributions are similar but not identical, and they should be this way. The joint distribution for the set of independent non-identical experiments is then
\begin{equation}
P(x_1,\dots,x_N)=\prod_{r=1}^Np^{(r)}_{x_r}.
\end{equation}
I take the distribution $P$ to be my null hypothesis.

Now I have a set of $r$ outcomes $\{y_r\}_{r=1,\dots,N}$, each one for the corresponding experiment $r$, and want to do something like a $p$-test to determine whether this outcome $\{y_r\}_{r=1,\dots,N}$ significantly deviates from the null hypothesis. This comes from an actual research project, and the values $\{y_r\}_{r=1,\dots,N}$ seem to all be on the low probability ends of the $p^{(r)}_x$.

First, is a $p$-test appropriate here? What I mean is, if I calculate the cumulative for $(x_1\leq y_1,\dots,x_N\leq y_N)$ and compare to $P(y_1,\dots,y_N)$, is this a reliable method to determine significant deviation from the null hypothesis? Second, would something like this actually be called a $p$-test? Finally, is my general intuition here correct in terms of testing, or am I not realising some important property here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you could do some sort of likelihood ratio test where you compare P(x)/P(y)  where the x maximize the likelihood. The details escape me at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the probability that the variables $x_r$ are less than or equal to your observations $y_r$, assuming the $x_r$ are distributed as assumed (this is the null hypothesis), you'll get the total probability of observing values at least as extreme as the ones you did observe.

$$
p = \prod_{r=1}^N \mathrm{Pr}(x_r\leq y_r)
$$

This is the definition of what's commonly called a $p$-value. If the $p$-value is small, it means that it is unlikely that you observed such extreme $y_r$ values by chance, given the null hypothesis. So, the assumed distributions for the variables is likely wrong, i.e. the null hypothesis is likely false. Specifically, you pick a cutoff for the $p$-value, typically $5\%$ or $1\%$ or smaller, and you say that you rejected the null-hypothesis at that level of significance.

Comment: Thank you rajb245. This clarifies my thinking.